# How to split an element in a character vector and insert it as a new element?

Tags: r, string, split

I have a character vector containing 5 elements. 4 elements contain a single name, but one element contains two names, separated by a comma.

For example:

```
string <- c("Eric", "John", "Dora", "Michael, James", "Susan")

string
[1] "Eric"           "John"           "Dora"           "Michael, James" "Susan"
```

I want to separate the fourth element into two separate elements, such that:

```
string

[1] "Eric"    "John"    "Dora"    "Michael" "James"   "Susan"
```

Surely, this should be very easy. Yet, I can't seem to figure it out.

When I use

```
strsplit(string, ",")
```

The result is a list.

I believe there are ways to convert that list to a data.frame and then stack those columns, but I wonder if there is some regex magic or `substring` code for this issue?

Comment: Just use `unlist` on that `strsplit`.

Comment: so `unlist(strsplit(string, ","))`

Comment: You may also consider splitting on `'\\s+'` so that extra spaces don't get retained as they would in your case of using `,` as split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right path with `strsplit`, just use `unlist` to get a vector.

```
> unlist(strsplit(string, ","))
[1] "Eric"    "John"    "Dora"    "Michael" " James"  "Susan"
```

Comment: Not sure how you got this result without the space on the front of "James" from "," as the split value.  I get `" James"`

Comment: @RichardScriven is right. Did you just modify your output to look nicer? This should be something like `unlist(strsplit(string, "\\s*,\\s*"))`. And it's better to not ignore comments that trying to improve ill-written answers because it will end up in downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `scan()` to avoid getting the list result all together.

```
scan(text = string, what = "", sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE)
# Read 6 items
# [1] "Eric"    "John"    "Dora"    "Michael" "James"   "Susan"
```

Comment: The `scan` function takes a very long time to compute on my real data. Do you know why that is the case? Just curious.

Comment: @wake_wake -How big is your real data?